# how to rename an aws code commit repo used by a cloud formation pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a cloud formation pipeline that sets up a step function and its corresponding lambda functions.  I store this all in a code commit repo called my-repo-test.

I want to rename the repo my-repo-test to product-name-dev.

Can I just rename the repository in code commit aws console, and repull it down? And then make my code changes and re commit/push it which then should execute the cloud formation pipeline to deploy and setup my step function?

I hope I am making sense.

We put a step function in a test repo and now that we decided to move forward with full development of this project we need to put it in its own properly name repository.

Best,